# Forbidden when posting events to Seq from Serilog.Sinks.Seq

Tags: serilog, seq

I have issue with posting logs from C# Console App to Seq. I am using NuGet package Serilog.Sinks.Seq for logging. In the console output I get error message:

```
Exception while emitting periodic batch from Serilog.Sinks.Seq.SeqSink: Serilog.Debugging.LoggingFailedException: Received failed result Forbidden when posting events to Seq
```

Seq is configured to accept all logs so it's not clear to me why logging to Seq is forbidden.

Source code of the console app:

```
using Serilog;
using System;

namespace SeqLogTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo.Seq("http://localhost:5341").CreateLogger();

            Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(Console.Error);

            Log.Warning("Hello Seq, it is warning!");

            Log.CloseAndFlush();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Hi! A couple of thoughts - is your Seq instance on Windows/installed with the MSI, or is it Docker/Linux? Can you access the Seq UI at the same (`localhost:5341`) address? Anything in the Seq ingestion log? _Settings > Diagnostics > Ingestion log_? Cheers!

Comment: @NicholasBlumhardt Hi, Seq is running on Windows and installed with the MSI. Seq is accessible fine via web on localhost:5341. Ingestion log contains only 1 line:
`The ingestion API is configured and accepting requests`.

Windows reboot didn't help. Thanks for reply!

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Do you see events in Seq if you run `seqcli log -m Hello` from the command-line?

Comment: @NicholasBlumhardt Yes, I can see logs sent form CLI.

Comment: I also tried running Seq in docker on Windows but still getting same error, although logging from seqcli works =/

Comment: In your Windows internet settings, do you have a proxy set up, and is it marked as "bypass for local addresses"? (Just brainstorming ideas - it's a bit of a tricky one!)

Comment: @NicholasBlumhardt yes I have corporate proxy setup in LAN Settings and option  "bypass for local addresses" is unchecked and I tried with checked option and added address "http://localhost:5341" to Exceptions in Advanced settings but it didn't work, am I doing it wrong or how it should be configured if the issue is related to networking? Thanks! P.S. I am using free 1-user license of seq, not sure if it may cause the described problem.

Comment: Hi Dima; it won't be single-user-version related, AFAIK. The proxy still seems like it may hold the clue, since your client app will also need to be picking up these settings; I wonder what happens if you use, say `http://localhost:5341/missing` as the server URL in your Serilog/Seq config? Seq should 404 this - if you still see "access denied", it'll point to the proxy being involved. Hope this helps!

Comment: @NicholasBlumhardt if I use "/missing" endpoint I still get "access denied" error, so yeah it seems like proxy is involved in the issue. Could you point out how to configure proxy for Serilog? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Dima; Serilog will use .NET's standard `HttpClient` under the hood, I think its proxy config will be consistent with the way the proxy is configured in the .NET version your app is running.

Comment: @NicholasBlumhardt I found out that proxy was fine, but the problem may be with user authentication as I have created "test" user for seq and authentication has been enabled. But my fellows at work are able to use Seq and the difference I found from my Seq is that they have authentication disabled. But I can't figure out how to disable that authentication to test this out.

Comment: Probably easier just to create an `Ingest` API key (from _Settings_ or your user prefs) and associate that with the logger; HTH!

Comment: Hi, I tried using api key with logger but it didn't help. I tried to reinstall Seq app but users data remains uncleared. Wondering how to make clean Seq install.

Comment: Hi Dima, to create a clean install, you can `seq stop` and then delete `C:\ProgramData\Seq`, before `seq start`ing again. HTH!

Comment: Hi Nicholas, I've managed to create a clean seq install, but still getting "Forbidden" error. Can't come up with other ideas how to solve it.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. This one's a bit of a puzzle! The next step might be to install Wireshark and collect a network trace to see where that request is going.

Answer (score 2):

So it turned out that the reason of the problem was incorrectly created Windows firewall rule which was supposed to allow connections on port 5341 but it wasn't working actually. After having deleted the rule, Seq started showing logs just fine.

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear you tracked it down.

Answer (score 1):

Have been witnessing a very peculiar problem with `seq` on windows that was not ingesting any logs, similar to what @dima-bondarenko was reporting.
The error message was slightly different `Failed with status code ServiceUnavailable (Service Unavailable)`
Nevertheless I'll leave some troubleshooting ideas in here as well, maybe one day someone might benefit from it :)

In our case, `serilog` was running along with a .net 5 api having `seq` as yet another sink.
The setup was working just fine out of the box, without any particular configuration on quite a few dev machines except one.
Logs ingestion simply did not work and nothing ended up being logged in seq.

Things to look after

- enable self log to surface the actual error

```
Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(Console.Error);
```

> `Failed with status code ServiceUnavailable (Service Unavailable)`

- push messages via the cli

```sh
seqcli log -m Hello
```

> `Failed with status code ServiceUnavailable (Service Unavailable)`

- inspect page with curl

```sh
curl http://localhost:5341
```

> sounded like the corporate proxy was interfering, though the `don't use the proxy for local addresses` proxy system setting was enabled

```html
<p>Generated Mon, 19 Apr 2021 12:27:26 GMT by proxy.some.domain.com</p>
<!-- ERR_CONNECT_FAIL -->
```

- inspect the environment variables

```sh
printenv HTTP_PROXY
```

> bingo, some docker leftovers might have altered the http proxy setting.
> removing the environment variable made the `seqcli` push happy again.

```sh
seqcli log -m "Hello again"
```

> but the application was still witnessing `Service Unavailable` though

- check firewall inbound rules for port `5341` as there was one rule similar to the bellow snippet

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Seq Open Port 5341" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=5341
```

> at first sight, removing the firewall inbound rule did not seem to have fixed the `Service Unavailable` though

- restart the machine

> and guess what, everything is back to normal again

At the end of the day `seq` is a fantastic product and generally speaking it just works :)
but sometimes the combination of some misconfiguration factors could easily ruin the day :)